# run jenkins job as logged in user dynamically without changing the "Run_as_user" on jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Jenkins is being used as platform for continous integration and delivery. While running a pipeline script in Jenkins ,i noticed the job run in the "Jenkins user" perspective and not by the logged in user . Is there a way that script can be executed by logged in user on the server instead of the jenkins system user.

Comment: Hi nitika, how is this job of yours triggered?

Comment: I have a job on jenkins that executes the pipeline scripts. I run it manually from the UI.